# Jekyll deployment error on Vercel due to Ruby version mismatch

Tags: ruby, jekyll, vercel, jekyll-theme

I'm trying to deploy a Jekyll site to Vercel using the [chirpy](https://chirpy.cotes.page/) theme; as per the documentation, I used the Chirpy Start template to create a new repo on my GitHub account, I cloned the repo and imported it to Vercel. Since I haven't modified anything in the original project I expected everything to work well so far, but when Vercel tried to build the site I got the error below:

[image]

Unless I am utterly mistaken, I understand that the error is caused because the Vercel server is running Ruby v2.7.0, instead of v3.0 or greater as mandated by the **jekyll-theme-chirpy** gem. I find this confusing, since according to [this post](https://vercel.com/changelog/upgrading-ruby-v2-7-to-v3-2), Vercel should be using Ruby v3.2.x by default:

[image]

In order to solve the problem, I've tried to change my Gemfile to specify a more recent Ruby version, and also I've tried to add a custom installation step on Vercel that runs a script to upgrade Ruby, but none of that has worked, so I've decided to ask for help; ideally I would like a solution that allows me to use the most up-to-date version of Chirpy, but if that's not possible I would be pleased if you could suggest Jekyll theme alternatives that work with Ruby v2.7.0.

Comment: How did you configure the Ruby version in your Gemfile?

Comment: @spickermann As in the Vercel post; `ruby "~> 3.2.x"`

Comment: The [official syntax for the Ruby directive](https://bundler.io/guides/gemfile_ruby.html) in a `Gemfile` doesn't support defining Ruby versions with a `x`. Try `ruby "~> 3.2.0"` instead.

Comment: Already tried it, but the result is the same; I still get an error saying that the Ruby version doesn't match